# C# Arranging icons and changing folder display

Tags: c#, windows, icons, directory

Is it possible to arrange icons (just placing them at different locations on the desktop/in folders), and if so, could someone point me in the right direction?

I'm also interested in changing the properties for a folder programmatically, like "Documents", "Pictures", "Detailed list" and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Similar question asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131690/how-can-i-programmatically-manipulate-windows-desktop-icon-locations

Comment: You can adapt [this C++ program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx) and call [`IFolderView::GetPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the position and [`IFolderView::SelectAndPositionItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to move them.

Comment: @RaymondChen link is broken. Know of another place to retrieve?

Comment: @JMIII You can find the link in web.archive.org.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks your blog has been great! Greatly appreciate all the work you do!

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20171025065411/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393