VirtualAllocEx - Memory reservation does not return an base address
I am currently working on a small C# project to save the names of the desktop icons in a text file.
I have used these two articles to help me get started:
Desktop Icon manipulation - how to get a handle to SysListView32 when themes with picture rotation are enabled
Getting the text of a all windows desktop shortcuts
Using FindWindow, FindWindowEx and SendMessage I was able to successfully determine the number of desktop icons (yeah, really 115 :-) ) and with GetWindowThreadProcessId the Thread Process Id. OpenProcess also returns a value.
The problem is that VirtualAllocEx always returns the value 0.
According to VirtualAllocEx - return-value, a memory address should be returned if the function succeeds:

If the function succeeds, the return value is the base address of the allocated region of pages. If the function fails, the return value is NULL.

GetLastError does not return an error.
I have read on various websites that the handling of memory management has changed since Windows Vista and that certain access parameters are no longer so easy to use.
Could this be the reason?
Many thanks for your help
Jolanda

System environment

Windows 10 22H2
Visual Studio 17.11.4 (C#-Tools 4.11.0)
.NET 8.0

Code
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DesktopIcon
{
    partial class DesktopIcon
    {
        internal const int LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = 0x00001000 + 4;
        internal const int LVIF_TEXT = 0x00000001;
        internal const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x00000008;
        internal const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x00000010;
        internal const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x00000020;
        internal const int MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000;
        internal const int MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
        internal const int PAGE_READWRITE = 0x00001000;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint GetLastError();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern void SetLastError(uint dwErrorCode);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint processId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetDesktopIcons();
        }

        public static void GetDesktopIcons()
        {
            // Reset last error
            SetLastError(0);

            // This buffer size will be enough.
            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 0x110;
            uint vProcessId = 0;

            try
            {
                // Find window handles via process names.
                IntPtr vHandle = FindWindow("Progman", "Program Manager");
                vHandle = FindWindowEx(vHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
                vHandle = FindWindowEx(vHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "FolderView");
                Console.WriteLine($"vHandle: {vHandle}");

                // Count subwindows of desktop => count of icons.
                int vIconCount = SendMessage(vHandle, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
                Console.WriteLine($"Count desktop icons (vIconCount): {vIconCount}");

                // Get the desktop window's process to enumerate child windows.
                int threadProcessId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(vHandle, out vProcessId);
                Console.WriteLine($"ThreadProcessId: {threadProcessId}");

                IntPtr vProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, false, vProcessId);
                Console.WriteLine($"vProcess: {vProcess}");

                // Allocate memory in the desktop process.
                IntPtr vPointer = VirtualAllocEx(vProcess, IntPtr.Zero, BUFFER_SIZE, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
                Console.WriteLine($"vPointer: {vPointer}");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"GetLastError: {GetLastError()}");
        }
    }
}


Your uint dwSize parameter declaration is incorrect: uint (UInt32) is always 32-bit in C#, but SIZE_T in Win32 has the same size as a pointer (so 64-bits on x64, but 32-bits on x86).

When doing interop, you should never redeclare GetLastError, but use the one provided by .NET, for example here Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() because .NET does Win32 calls too, so when you read it using the API, it's too late. You will see the error is ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED. Also, there's an official API for this sort of thing: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933

You really shouldn't be messing about with Explorer private memory, MS explicitly say this is subject to implmentation changes. Raymond Chen (MS employee) shows how you are really supposed to do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020228/how-to-move-desktop-icons-using-winapi-on-c

Thank you very much for your help. I will read up on IFolderView and try again.
