# Place an image in a specific locaton on a windows desktop using python

Tags: python, windows, image

I wish to use python to place an image (say jpg or bmp) at a specific location on my Windows 7 desktop. I would also like the ability to drag it around using the mouse and for the python code to store it's final locations coordinates. So when Windows restarts (with the python code configured to run at startup), it reads the stored location and places the image back at its previous location.

Is this possible to do?
If it is, could someone please provide some suggestions on how to do it, as my python experience is pretty limited?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [LVM_SETITEMPOSITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761192%28VS.85%29.aspx) for arranging icons on the desktop.

There are a similar questions:

- [How can I programmatically manipulate Windows desktop icon
  locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131690/how-can-i-programmatically-manipulate-windows-desktop-icon-locations)
- [win32 programming](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/173093/win32-programming)

Python is not the best choice for this job, but if it's required try to look in to - commctrl, win32gui, and pywin32 libraries

Comment: That's not how you interact with the shell. The shell has an official API for this. Hacking at the underlying controls is not the way to do it.

Comment: @ton1c Thanks ton1c, it is preferable for me use Python as there is a number of other things happening in the background (and I want Python practice). I had a quick look at the Python libraries you suggested and couldn't make much sense of them, but I'll have a more thorough look and see what I can work out. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Which shell are you refering too?