# Is it possibly copy files and position them in my folder with x y coordinates?

Tags: windows, winapi, batch-file, position, directory

Really out there question but, I wanted to create a batch script or (any script) to copy files in a folder be able to position them around in a folder window in a particular arrangement. For example, if I apply the script to my desktop or current open window then it arranges all my shortcuts and files to create an "X" pattern or a circle. Is it possible to XCOPY in a batch file and apply x & y positioning? What language would have control over lets say my Windows 8 or Windows 7 Desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially like answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131690/how-can-i-programmatically-manipulate-windows-desktop-icon-locations). The desktop is a Listview which supports setting icon locations. You would need a little program to be used after your copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible, since Windows Vista it would only work maybe on the Desktop, or in a "place" that is facilitated by a Shell Extension, like the desktop. Or unless I am mistaken Explorer no longer arranges items in any view. Try to reposition one yourself. It should pop back into its sorted order in a perfect grid (unless you are using XP or a pre-XP version.)

I once had a self-extracting archive have one of its files way off several scroll screens away  (all by itself) in its folder after extraction. It was two years before I ever noticed that file. It was part of a patch. I'd thought the file lost to time.