# How to programmatically move desktop icons with java

Tags: java, windows, icons, desktop

Simple as that, is there a way to programmatically move desktop icons specifically with Java?

I'm going for something similar to stardock fences here. I want to make a program that starts with windows, and puts all of my icons where they are supposed to be. How can I go about this in Java specifically?

If Java isn't plausible, what language would it be easiest to make this in?

Comment: Java, being specifically designed to "run anywhere", is probably a bad choice for what sounds like a Windows utility.

Comment: @SteveH. Maybe so. I'm just trying to work with what I know. The only other programming language I'm proficient in (not that I'm overly proficient in Java) is C, and I can only imagine what hell it would be to make a program of this sort in C.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll be working directly with Windows, I think your best bet is going to be C#. It's very similar to Java, so it will be a bit smoother for you. Perhaps this will help answer your question: [How can I programmatically manipulate Windows desktop icon locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131690/how-can-i-programmatically-manipulate-windows-desktop-icon-locations)